# FactoryGirl::create throwing NoMethodError: undefined method `stringify_keys'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have the follwing in my factories.rb:

```
factory :ffsupervisor, class: Supervisor do
 first_name    "ffsupervisor" 
 email         "ffsupervisor@abc.com"
 password      "123456"
 type          "Supervisor"
 association :agency, name: "FFAgency", full_fee: "2.0", partial_fee: "1.0", agency_type: "Fulfilment"
end
```

I'm able to build and save an instance of Supervisor in my DB with `FactoryGirl::create(:ffsupervisor)` in the Rails Console. When I try to do the same thing in my feature specs, I end up getting:

NoMethodError: undefined method `stringify_keys'.

I've looked into a lot of questions in SO regarding this issue. Haven't been able to figure out what I'm missing out though. Any heads up on this would be great. TIA!

EDIT:
This is the stack trace I'm getting:

```
1) Workflow order_item lifecycle.
 Failure/Error: @supervisor= FactoryGirl::create(:ffsupervisor) # Creates both agency & supervisor.
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `stringify_keys' for #<Supervisor:0x0000000baa9410>
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activemodel-4.0.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:436:in `method_missing'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:131:in `method_missing'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:17:in `assign_attributes'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:192:in `initialize'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:47:in `initialize'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:27:in `new'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:27:in `new'
 # ./app/mailers/synup_mailer.rb:13:in `confirmation_instructions'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__1572042514373682743__process_action__callbacks'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionmailer-4.0.0/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:503:in `process'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionmailer-4.0.0/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:497:in `initialize'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/resque_mailer-2.2.6/lib/resque_mailer.rb:121:in `new'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/resque_mailer-2.2.6/lib/resque_mailer.rb:121:in `actual_message'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/resque_mailer-2.2.6/lib/resque_mailer.rb:97:in `initialize'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/resque_mailer-2.2.6/lib/resque_mailer.rb:40:in `new'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/resque_mailer-2.2.6/lib/resque_mailer.rb:40:in `method_missing'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:173:in `send_devise_notification'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:102:in `send_confirmation_instructions'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:158:in `send_on_create_confirmation_instructions'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:397:in `_run__462299154380556768__create__callbacks'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:303:in `create_record'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `create_record'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:466:in `create_or_update'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:299:in `block in create_or_update'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:393:in `_run__462299154380556768__save__callbacks'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:299:in `create_or_update'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:128:in `save!'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/validations.rb:57:in `save!'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:41:in `save!'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:275:in `block in save!'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/ar_after_transaction-0.4.0/lib/ar_after_transaction.rb:19:in `block in transaction_with_after'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `block in transaction'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:210:in `within_new_transaction'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `transaction'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/ar_after_transaction-0.4.0/lib/ar_after_transaction.rb:17:in `transaction_with_after'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:323:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:275:in `save!'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.2.0/lib/factory_girl/configuration.rb:14:in `block in initialize'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.2.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluation.rb:15:in `[]'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.2.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluation.rb:15:in `create'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.2.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:12:in `block in result'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.2.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:9:in `tap'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.2.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:9:in `result'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.2.0/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:42:in `run'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.2.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:23:in `block in run'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.2.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:22:in `run'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.2.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:19:in `block in define_singular_strategy_method'
 # ./spec/features/workflow_spec.rb:39:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:114:in `instance_eval'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:114:in `block in run'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:179:in `call'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:179:in `run'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_exec'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_eval_with_args'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:247:in `instance_eval_with_args'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:87:in `block (2 levels) in run'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:89:in `call'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:89:in `run'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:418:in `run_hook'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:329:in `run_around_each_hooks'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:256:in `with_around_each_hooks'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:111:in `run'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:390:in `block in run_examples'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:386:in `map'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:386:in `run_examples'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:371:in `run'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in run'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `map'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block in run'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:34:in `report'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:25:in `run'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
 # /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace from the error, and tell us which line in your code the error refers to. (In RSpec you may have to use the `--backtrace` option to see the full trace.)

Comment: @Jordan, just added the stack trace. :)

Comment: Are you including `rails_helper`? Rails isn't loaded without it, and that's where `stringify_keys` comes from.

Comment: @DaveNewton, I'm just requiring the spec_helper.rb inside the spec file. Don't really understand what the rails_helper is?

Comment: `stringify_keys` actually comes from the [ActiveSupport](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/Keys.html#M000945) module. It may be the case that ActiveSupport isn't being properly loaded when your run your specs. Try adding `require 'active_support/core_ext'` to the top of your Supervisor model file to identify if that's the issue.

Comment: @mralexlau, Nope. I got the same thing even  after the require. :(

Comment: Add the rails helper, I'm guessing you're running under RSpec 3+?

Comment: @DaveNewton `guard-rspec (3.1.0)` 
`rspec (2.13.0)` 
`rspec-core (2.13.1)` 
`rspec-expectations (2.13.0)` 
`rspec-mocks (2.13.1)` 
`rspec-rails (2.13.1)`

Those are the versions of my rspec gems. How and where do I add the rails helper?

Comment: What version of rails are you using? Looks like rspec 2 [had issues with loading activesupport](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-99/docs/changelog) with rails 4.1

Comment: @mralexlau, I'm using rails 4.0.0.

Comment: Try rake db:test:prepare

Comment: @DonatasStundys, Tried that before. Didn't help much. I don't really know what is causing this issue. When I'm able to create a record in my rails console, I don't know why I'm not able to do it in my specs. :(

Comment: Are you able to create records in your specs without FactoryGirl?

Comment: @DonatasStundys, yes. Right now, I'm using the `FactoryGirl::attributes_for(@instance)` to create a hash and then passing it to the `Model.new(@hash)` method and then doing a `Model.save!`. I know this isn't a good workaround. But this is how I'm able to create records in my specs. :(